# PHP 7.1 Doctrine proxy issue with nullable types

Tags: php, doctrine, php-7.1

I am working with the new feature of php7.1 that allow to return a nullable type on a project Symfony 3, but I have an issue when using this in an entity:

```
<?php
// ....
public function getCreatedBy(): ?string
{
    return $this->createdBy;
}
```

When I am using this function I have this error:

```
Type error: Return value of 
Proxies\\__CG__\\NS\\ModulesBundle\\Entity\\Account::getCreatedBy() 
must be of the type string, null returned
```

I taked a look to the code of the class created automatically with Symfony and I found this:

```
<?php
// ...
public function getCreatedBy(): string
{

    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getCreatedBy', []);

    return parent::getCreatedBy();
}
```

As you can see, the type is not nullable.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes, i cleared the cache

Comment: This is Doctrine related issue, not to Symfony itself.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the problem by upgrading the lib doctrine/doctrine-common to the version 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by upgrading from the version 2.6 to the version 2.8 of doctrine/doctrine-common library